# Swift - Unable to get information from http links

Tags: ios, swift

I'm facing a problem with a feature of my application that enables a user to share links with other users. Once the link has been shared, it appears as a clickable view that contains some information about the corresponding webpage (coming from the Open Graph protocol in the HTML code) such as the title, the "main image", etc. This works perfectly fine when the website uses HTTPS.

However, when it only uses HTTP, I'm getting the following error:

> NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
>   App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.

Thanks to my research I have found that the solution is to turn off App Transport Security by adding the following lines to info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
```

However, in the official documentation, it is specified that Apple would likely reject any app using this tag. The best solution would be to add exceptions for specific domains but I cannot really guess which links are going to be shared...

Would you have any solution for me?

Comment: I have used those plist settings combined with the domain specification in my app, which has been approved only yesterday. So although Apple probably isn't happy with it you **can** upload and publish apps with that

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for dev no problem. I have seen people on SO mention that they have released apps to the app store using this also.

The solution for production is to add your specific hosts that you need access to instead of `AllowsArbitraryLoads`.

Of course, the actual answer to this is to use `https` and not bypass ATS at all.

Comment: I know this but the problem is that I am not the one who are going to choose the links. It is the user that chooses the link they want to share. So if the user shares a link to a website that does not use HTTPS, they won't be able to do so.